# JFrame doesn't add TabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtabbedpane

My JFrame is not adding the JTabbedPane and I don't know if the crash is some sort of bug of my eclipse. There are no syntaxes errors or anything that seems to be to me wrong. Could anyone else try to run it and see if it works? The code is already ready to run. Thanks in advance

```
public class MainScreen extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JMenuBar bar;
    JMenu file, register;
    JMenuItem close, search;
    ImageIcon logo= new ImageIcon("rsc/img/sh-logo.jpg");
    ImageIcon worldIcon= new ImageIcon("rsc/img/world-icon.png");
    JLabel lbImage1;
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    JPanel entrance = new JPanel();

    public MainScreen()
    {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();

        lbImage1= new JLabel(logo, JLabel.CENTER);
        entrance.add(lbImage1);
        tabbedPane.addTab("SHST", worldIcon, entrance);
        mainFrame.add( tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        bar= new JMenuBar();
        file= new JMenu("File");
        register= new JMenu("Search");

        close= new JMenuItem("Close");
        close.addActionListener(this);

        search= new JMenuItem("Request Query");
        search.addActionListener(this);

        //Keyboard Shortcut
        register.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        file.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        search.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R);

        //mainFrame Setup
        bar.add(file);
        bar.add(register);
        file.add(close);
        register.add(search);
        mainFrame.add(bar);
        mainFrame.setExtendedState(getExtendedState() | mainFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); // Maximized Window or setSize(getMaximumSize());
        mainFrame.setTitle("SHST");
        mainFrame.setJMenuBar(bar);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(0);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

            WindowListener J=new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
            System.exit(0);
            }
        }; 

        addWindowListener(J);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource()==close){
            System.exit(0);
        }
        }

public static void main (String[] args){
        MainScreen m= new MainScreen();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method from `ActionListener`.

Comment: actually is there, i forgot to copy here

Comment: 1) A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough. 2) Don't extend frame or other top level containers.  Instead create & use an instance of one. 3) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.   4) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 5) There is no point adding a `WindowAdapter` to a `JFrame` here.  Instead call `setDefaultClosOperation(int)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've added JMenuBar in Content pane. It is not required.

remove this line in your code `mainFrame.add(bar);` and `mainFrame.setJMenuBar(bar);` is already added.

Answer (score 0):

Yout must not add the `JTabbedPane` directly into your `JFrame` (`mainFrame.add(tabbedPane,...)`) but add it do the contentPane instead: `mainFrame.getContentPane().add( tabbedPane, ...)`

Comment: That will make no difference since about Java 1.5(?).

Comment: There is a property(`rootPaneCheckingEnabled`) to control this(but I don't know why you would want to turn it off).

Comment: Ah thanks, I see one should more carefully read about changes from one JAVA version to another. I knew the issue from earlier JAVA releases